# Selenium - Why search results are returning me list of same elements from the Web serach

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I am trying a simple program on python selenium, using firefox browser. I want to search something and grab all the results in a list. For instance, search a text on youtube and print all the results' xref and labels.

Following is my code. And the result prints 1st element X number of times.

```
class youtube:
base_url = "https://www.youtube.com/"

search_textbox_xpath = "//input[@id='search']"
search_button_id = "search-icon-legacy"

all_results_xpath = "//ytd-video-renderer[contains(@class,'ytd-item-section-renderer')]"
individual_result_href_xpath = "//a[@id='video-title']"
individual_result_text_xpath = "//a[@id='video-title']/yt-formatted-string[contains(@class,'ytd-video-renderer')]"

def search_youtube(self, search_text):
    try:
        b = Browser()
        handle = b.open_browser(self.base_url)
        time.sleep(8)

        search_textbox = handle.find_element_by_xpath(self.search_textbox_xpath)
        #search_textbox.clear()
        search_textbox.send_keys(search_text)

        handle.find_element_by_id(self.search_button_id).click()
        time.sleep(8)

        all_results = handle.find_elements_by_xpath(self.all_results_xpath)

        for each_result in all_results:
            print (each_result)
            href = each_result.find_element_by_xpath(self.individual_result_href_xpath).get_attribute('href')
            print(href)
            text = each_result.find_element_by_xpath(self.individual_result_text_xpath).text
            print(text)

    finally:
        b.close_browser()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = youtube()
    y.search_youtube('upcoming animated movies 2020')
```

Output:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSyecJ0zAQ
The Best Upcoming ANIMATION And FAMILY Movies 2020 (Trailer)

I can see that in 'each_result' different element id is referred. Then why it prints the same 1st result X number of times? I opened the same search and I can see in the source all the search results.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this: https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-  (basically your XPATH is still searching the entire context... use ".//" instead which limits it to children of the current WebElement.)

Comment: Thanks a ton, pcalkins! It worked with this simple change!